# How read chunk files and show as pdf in android?

Tags: android, pdf

Is it possible to convert a pdf file to some chunks and then read that chunks and display that chunks in PdfViewer android?
If it is possible, please guide me how do that.

I found this method for convert pdf to chunks:

```
private void getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file); //videorecorder stores video to file

    java.nio.channels.FileChannel fc = is.getChannel();
    java.nio.ByteBuffer bb = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);

    int chunkCount = 0;

    byte[] bytes;

    while(fc.read(bb) >= 0){
        bb.flip();
        //save the part of the file into a chunk
        bytes = bb.array();
        storeByteArrayToFile(bytes, mRecordingFile + "." + chunkCount);//mRecordingFile is the (String)path to file
        chunkCount++;
        bb.clear();
    }
}

private void storeByteArrayToFile(byte[] bytesToSave, String path) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
    try {
        fOut.write(bytesToSave);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        fOut.close();
    }
}
```

I used [AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) for displaying pdf but if you know other library or method to show pdf, please mention it.
Thanks.

Comment: What is "PdfViewer android"?

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean something like https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: Unless each of your chunks is a standalone PDF, you would need to talk to the developer of that PDF viewer to determine what sorts of streaming options are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with help of PDF Linearization. Basically this is a standard feature in PDF where data is organized in such way to enable on-demand streaming of content. For this to work you will also need to use a PDF Viewer that supports linearization (for example https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/android/guides/viewer/view-online-pdfs/ )